# How to remove the tagline from the HTML <title>?

Tags: customization

I'm using the default Wordpress 2011 theme on a new blog I'm setting up. I've got everything basically setup fine for now. I have experience with PHP/MySQL and HTML/CSS, but haven't used WordPress as yet.

When I set the blog up, it asked for a tagline under general settings, which I provided. This is showing below the blog heading, which is fine, however I don't want it to appear in the HTML title.

At the moment the `<title>` element looks like this: "Blog Name | Tagline". I just want the blog name.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, figured it out.

In `/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php`, you can comment out this:

```
// Add the blog description for the home/front page.
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";
```

Then the blog tagline won't be added for the front page.